# C# and Bluetooth Programming

Tags: c#, bluetooth

How can this be done?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144862/bluetooth-apis-in-windows-net

Comment: What specific task are you trying to accomplish - when you say 'Bluetooth programming' ?

Answer (score 4):

http://inthehand.com/content/32feet.aspx

Answer (score 1):

to the bluetooth programming you need to add 32feet apis.