# C# Writing Bluetooth protocol

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, protocols

I am looking to write a Bluetooth protocol implementation in C# i.e. All kind of request (discovery etc) must be handled by my application. But I have no idea that from where should I start. Any suggestion? reference?

Comment: maybe this question would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824357/c-and-bluetooth-programming

Comment: The first thing you might want to do is get familiar with the Bluetooth specification: https://www.bluetooth.org/apps/content/

Comment: I am no interested in using Bluetooth API but writing a custom API for myself. The actual need is to modify Bluetooth protocol for a special requirement. I can read Bluetooth specification but question what should I do in order to implement these specification. A more simpler question might that I want to respond all device discovery request received by my device/computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Various companies have produced Bluetooth software "stacks" for Windows: Microsoft themselves, Widcomm/Broadcom, IVT BlueSoleil, Toshiba, etc.  As far as I know none of the stacks let you see the low level requests for responding to discovery ("Inquiry"), and its unlikely that they would do so.

I'm not even sure that the software level sees such requests, doesn't the radio answer inquiry requests itself -- check with the HCI interface so see if there's a inquiry request received (or simimalr named) event.  I can't remember such an event.

BTW my library [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/) provides .NET support for Bluetooth, OBEX and IrDA, on Windows: desktop and WM/CE, and in development for Blue+Linux+Mono.  (I'm presuming you are on Windows based on the request for C#).

Comment: Is there any open source implementation of "stack"? So I can change it my self...