# Mobile remote program

Tags: c#, java, android

I'm writing a mobile remote program that the mobile's touch screen will be the remoted computer mouse. I'm using android for mobile and C# for server side programming.

Question:

- How can I establish a data connection between a mobile phone and
  computer that passes mouse position continuously without stopping?

I found [32feet.net](http://32feet.codeplex.com/) that is free class library about Bluetooth but I couldn't solve my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: : You found the solution ? If yes, please do post it as I am also trying out something similar. Cheers!

Comment: I didn't.  I don't know why no one answers this! @swayam

Comment: Upvoted so that you may get more attention. :)

Comment: What is special about this problem? Simply implement a server/client network protocol between the phone and computer and pass the information you require using well established techniques. Also I would imagine Bluetooth would not be the first choice for transport -- not many desktop/laptop computers have native Bluetooth.

Comment: Thank you @JcMalta for response. You are right, I want to implement a simple server/client network but I don't know how. I can receive some files from my mobile phone on my server program that I wrote with 32feet.net class library but it isn't my goal because it receives a file. After writing it on a path I can read it but the thing that I need is a data connection that it can receive data as integer and read it on time. I want to use Bluetooth for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to establish a client server connection and send information through a bluetooth socket.
Therefor you need a C# Bluetooth API or if it doesnt exist you write your own with sockets.

What would make your life easier i think is to use Java instead of C# for the server side as android uses Java, thats my opinion.

But i suggest you read more about how the Bluetooth protocol works with android and C#
Here are 2 links that will probably help you get started.

[C# and Bluetooth Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824357/c-sharp-and-bluetooth-programming)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

I hope that helps you.