# Programmatically controlling a bluetooth phone

Tags: c#, sdk, bluetooth

I want to write a program in C# that will allow me to place phone calls through my phone and receive phone calls through my PC speakers and microphone via bluetooth. I have never done bluetooth programming and I am hoping someone can point me to an open source or free .NET library for bluetooth programming, specifically to do the functions I requested. I am using a Broadcom BT2250 bluetooth dongle. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144862/bluetooth-apis-in-windows-net